# Preserving appeal process

Tags: united-states, civil-procedure

If a motion to dismiss is granted on one of several defendnats 'with prejudice' is there anything that must be done to preserve an appeal of the order granting dismissal whether or not it was done 'with prejudice?

Answer (score 1):

Generally not. Unless the judge certifies the right to make a separate appeal with regard to those parties, the judgment is not final.